# How can I change font size of pagination part in material table using react js?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, components, material-ui, material-table

I want to increase the font size for the pagination part of the material table footer.

In the below image, I am able to change the font size of rows per page with the below code

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjNmp.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDXWo.png)

```
components={{
    Pagination: props => (
      <TablePagination
        {...props}

        SelectProps={{
          style:{
            fontSize: 20
          }
        }}
      />
    )
  }}
```

but still unable to change increase size of the whole underlined part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I styled both caption area using two different methods: One via toolbar styles and the other directly:

There is two parts in the `results per page` component and are a `p` by default

```
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  caption: {
    color: "green",
    padding: 8,
    border: "1px dashed grey",
    fontSize: "0.875rem"
  },
  toolbar: {
    "& > p:nth-of-type(2)": {
      fontSize: "1.25rem",
      color: "red",
      fontWeight: 600
    }
  }
});

// then later

const classes = useStyles();
<TablePagination 
      // ...
      classes={{
        toolbar: classes.toolbar,
        caption: classes.caption
      }}
    />
```

Here is a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-field-f26zt)

Comment: this piece of code is properly working in function styled coding but i am using classes so is there any suggestion for that?

Comment: yes, `const StyledTablePagination = withStyles(stylesObject)(TablePagination)`

Comment: withStyles is a material-ui HOC for composing styles